# How can I get the tempfile path of active storage in rails 6

Tags: image-processing, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6

> I am upgrading my rails 5.2 to rails 6. Following is my old code wherein `object_path`I get `/tmp/image_processing20191218-32740-qqg8h3.jpg`

```
def load_image_path(key)
  if %w[development test].include? Rails.env
    path = ActiveStorage::Blob.service.send(:path_for, key)
    object_path = ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.source(path).call.to_path
  else
    object = S3.new.bucket.object key
    object_path = object.presigned_url(:get)
  end
  object_path
end
```

> Now as the image magic is removed from active storage this `ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.source(path).call.to_path` don't work. Does anyone know the alternative? I need this path before the blob is stored in the DB

Answer (score 2):

> After research I have found, Rails 6 changed the moment of uploading the file to storage to during the actual save of the record. This means that a before_save or validation cannot access the file the regular way. If you need to access the newly uploaded file you can get a file reference like this:

```
record.attachment_changes['<attributename>'].attachable
```

> This will be a temp file of the to-be-attached file.